# bind ajax:success getting called even if the element is not the one selected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am facing a issue where `ajax:success` is getting triggered even when the event is not fired on the target element.

```
    jQuery(document).bind('ajax:success', '.delete-dashboard-filter', function(e) {
      console.log('surprisingly in here');
    });

    jQuery(document).bind('ajax:success', '.delete-csv-export', function() {
      console.log('listing csv exports....');
    }).
```

In my code above, when I click on element with class `delete-csv-export`, both the ajax:success events are triggered and i see both executing

```
console.log('surprisingly in here');
console.log('listing csv exports....');
```

The relevant `html` for both the links is generated below

```
    <%= link_to path1(:id => obj.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'delete-dashboard-filter' do%>
      <%= inline_svg 'icons/trash.svg' %>
    <%end%>

    <%= link_to path2(:id => obj.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, :class => 'delete-csv-export' do%>
      <%= inline_svg 'icons/trash.svg' %>
    <%end%>
```

Is there something that I am doing incorrectly, I would expect that ajax:success corresponding to the element will be executed instead of both.

Comment: What exactly does the related HTML look like?

Comment: @Pointy, i have updated the question with the relevant code that generates html.

Comment: That's not HTML; it would be more helpful to see what the actual markup that makes it to the browser looks like.

Comment: `jQuery.bind` was depreciated eons ago. Use `jQuery.on`.

Comment: hi @max, thanks for your reply. Yes i fixed it with `jQuery.on`